# Im not able to see modules in help list in PyCharm

Tags: python, user-interface, module, pycharm, discord

im a newbie in python and for now im creating a discord bot. I watch some tutorials on YouTube from a guy who does the same thing but in Microsoft Visual Studio Code, i work in PyCharm. And you know how there is the thing that helps you with a list of all things you can type next. That guy has modules included too but i dont and i would like to know how im able to turn it on. Thank you for help

[My code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p999R.png)

[His code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b7Pe.png)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what are you trying to do, with your code. Also, could you add your code as text instead of an image, we can't copy the text easily and help you this way.

Comment: Well, i know its hard to understand. But for example when i type ´´discord.Status.´´ after the last dot a window pop up with a list of all things you can type next. As you can see in the first image. But my problem is that i dont have modules included there like the guy has in the second image. Thats why i didnt add my code because its not related with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your quastion but if i got it right you need to install those packeges with pip. try to write pip install and the librerys you need to use in the cmd